# PostgreSQL: Import database dump (.sql) in Azure Space such as Azure Function, Azure Data Factory, ETC

Tags: azure-functions, azure-data-factory, large-files, database-restore, azure-postgresql

I have a GB PostgreSQL database dump. I need to import it into an Azure postgreSQL single server.
I know the below command but I prefer the import done inside DB without command line in the hosting OS environment.

- psql -U postgres -d mydatabase -f dumpfile.sql

Is there any db sql command to do the psql -f command job? For example, the MS sql server has several ways to do that (BULK INSERT, etc.) without powershell command line. Does pgSQL have similar functions?

Answer (score 1):

To import dump file there is only option to use psql command or `\i 'path file'` command through command line. To avoid command line, you can use **`pgadmin`** tool to work with Azure Postgres SQL database. Steps are as follows.

1. Connect your **Azure Postgres SQL to pgadmin**.
2. Right click on Your `Database Name`.
3. Click on `Restore`.
4. Select file `dumpfile.sql`.
5. Click on `Restore`.

File will import successfully.

Comment: Is it possible to execute psql command in the Azure function Powershell? I thought pgSQL may have a statement like "restore database myDB from 'c:\db\mydb.bak'" in SQL server.

Comment: There is [pg_restore](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/postgresql/migrate/how-to-migrate-using-dump-and-restore#restore-the-data-into-the-target-database) command to restore the data into the target database from the dump file.

Comment: Is there any command for .sql dump file too?